# Independence of events involving geometric Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Consider the event: $A_n:= \{S(t_n) >z_{n-1}S(t_{n-1})\}$ with $z_{n-1}=e^{\sqrt{t_n-t_{n-1}}}, t_k \in [0,T)$.

$S(t_n) $ is an geometric Brownian motion, meaning: $S(t_n)  = \exp\left( \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)t_n + \sigma W(t_n)\right)$

How can I argue that the events $A_k$ are independent?

Comment: Can you express $A_n$ in terms of $W(t_n)-W(t_{n-1})$ ?

Comment: Yes I can write $W(t_n)-W(t_{n-1}) > \frac{1}{\sigma} \sqrt{t_n - t_{n-1}}+ (\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}) (t_{n-1} -t_n)  )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variables $X_n$ defined as
$$X_n:=\ln\frac{S(t_n)}{S(t_{n-1})}=(\mu-0.5\sigma^2)(t_{n}-t_{n-1})+\sigma(W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}})$$
depend only on the Brownian increments $\Delta W_{t_n}:=W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}}$, which are independent between each other by definition. The following equivalence holds:
$$\{S(t_n)>S(t_{n-1})z_{n-1}\}=\{X_n>\sqrt{t_n-t_{n-1}}\}$$
Since $X_n$ and $X_k$ are independent $\forall n \neq k$, we have that
$$P(X_n>\sqrt{t_n-t_{n-1}},X_k>\sqrt{t_k-t_{k-1}})=P(X_n>\sqrt{t_n-t_{n-1}})P(X_k>\sqrt{t_k-t_{k-1}})$$

Comment: Thank you very much.  I got it:)

Comment: You're welcome @Alif